# How can a DMM measure open circuit voltage?

Tags: voltage, adc, multimeter

This question has bugged me for some time now. How can a DMM measure open circuit voltage?

I have a general grasp of how ADCs work.  How is an open circuit voltage measured when that should produce a voltage drop because of the battery's internal resistance?

Comment: Why would the battery's internal resistance have any effect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's have a look a multimeter mearuring the voltage from a battery:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhMe2V.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The battery contains a perfect voltage source and an internal resistance.  The multimeter contains a perfect voltmeter (it draws no current) with a large resistor in parallel.

With typical values for the internal resistance of the battery and the internal resistance of the meter, there's no measurable drop across the battery's internal resistance - the measured voltage is the same as the voltage source to three decimal places.

If I change the resistances (quite) a bit, then you can see a voltage drop across the battery's internal resistance:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHPJG7.png)</sup>

A small coin or button cell could easily have an internal resistance as high as 1000 ohms.  Back in the old days when voltmeters were built with hand wound coils for the mechanical movement, it wouldn't be unusual to have a voltmeter with a resistance as low as 40000 ohms.

Those conditions make it obvious that a multimeter does have an effect on the measured voltage.

For modern meters and normal batteries, the effect is unnoticeable.

People speak of the open circuit voltage as the voltage measured with the voltmeter because the difference is too small to matter for most things.

Here's another example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCC39B.png)</sup>

That's a modern multimeter measuring the voltage of a battery with a very high internal resistance.

Does that 1/1000 of a volt matter?  Most of the time, no.

Maybe you are experimenting with nano batteries for your nanobots.  Such small batteries would have a (very) high internal resistance - so high that a normal multimeter would distort the readings.  In that case you'd reach for a (really expensive) specialist volt meter with an input resistance in the gigaohm range - and a specialist to help you make sure that your connections are properly made and shielded to let you measure things that finely.

---

The circuit diagrams are also simulator models.  You can open them in your browser and change the values to see how things work.  (The simulator won't work in a smartphone or tablet.  You need a laptop or PC with a mouse to use it.)

Comment: Thank u so much this really helped. But what if we put a 2 ohm resistor in series to the internal resistance. Won't that 2 ohm resistor now be parallel to the 10Mohm shunt? So shouldn' that output a voltage approximating the Vsource and not a very small voltage value? But when we I do that andthen measure it, it gives me about 0.70 V (at te node of the 2 ohm resistor).

Comment: Ohhhh I get it now, since they're parallel, that would effectively mean that the two resistor's equivalent value should drop.

Answer (score 9):

Try putting some numbers on the effect of internal resistance. A small battery such as an AA might have an internal resistance in the range of 1\$\Omega\$.

Multimeters usually have input resistances of 1M\$\Omega\$ to >10G\$\Omega\$. At the lower end of the scale, the 1.5V battery would be supplying 1.5\$\mu\$A to the meter, so the effect of the internal resistance would be 1.5\$\mu\$V, which is 1 part in a million - utterly negligible in  relation to the 1.5V battery voltage (it will change that much with small temperature changes, for example). The better meters will have proportionally less effect (10,000 times better for the 10G input). There is actually current flowing (it's not really "open circuit") but the effect of the current is negligible so we call it 'open circuit voltage'.

To have even less effect it's not very hard to build a meter that measures relatively low voltages with a bias current in the fA range (eg. LMP7721 with typical +/-3fA input bias current). That's 500 million times better than the cheap multimeter. That would be useful if you had a very high impedance source (not an ordinary battery).

A measurement principle that, in theory anyway, draws zero current once it has reached steady state is the Kolbe gold-leaf electroscope, however they are not very sensitive (better for measuring kV than volts). Any current is because insulators are not perfect. This is also possible with MOSFETs (the gate voltage appears across an insulator) however most MOSFETs and MOSFET-input op-amps have protection networks that leak significant current. Early MOSFETs were sometimes shipped with a spring shorting clip around the leads which had to be removed after soldering.

The only current that flows in a Kolbe electroscope is to charge the input capacitance, after that it would be zero if the insulators were perfect.

Comment: Another way for measuring voltage with minimal current draw is to use another, adjustable voltage source in series with the meter. That way the voltage drop over the meter is smaller and thus the current draw is smaller also.

Comment: @jpa true, we had devices called “portable potentiometers” that combined precision resistors and a wirewound pot with a very sensitive mirror galvanometer. You would calibrate the pot to a standard cell and then measure the unknown voltage, in each case by nulling the galvo.

Answer (score 6):

A DMM may have an internal resistance of 10 mega ohms. So the current drawn is small enough that it doesn't cause an issue for typical usage.

But see "burden voltage".

Comment: I still don't get it. I mean say I measure a 9 volt battery in an open circuit, the DMM gives me a 9V reading. But when I measure the same battery in a closed circuit with a 2ohm resisteor it gives me a significantly lower reading, as 1.8 V. Meaning internal resistance affected the reading, how does it do that? I mean measure the 9Voc without being affected by the internal resistance?

Comment: No open circuit! The DMM has an input resistance: 10 Mohm is 6 orders of magnitude larger than 2 ohms. Try your experiments with pregressively larger resistors and plot the results as voltage against conductance (reciprocal of load resistance). Then you’ll understand and clearly see that once the load impedance is “big”, there’s almost no voltage change – at least none that you can measure with a low precision multimeter. **No meter gives you open circuit voltage – no such device exists**.

Answer (score 1):

**You never measure open circuit voltage**. It’s not physically possible. But you can get arbitrarily close in practice :)

Thus no multimeter can provide such a value directly, because measuring open circuit voltage is an abstract idea.

A DMM gives you *not* an open circuit reading, but a reading across a 10Mohm resistor (typically). Cheapest DMMs (in the $10 range) present lower impedances, but 10Mohm is the value everyone expects from mainstream tools.

Most battery impedances, and plenty node impedances in common circuits, are so low compared to 10Mohm, that the shunting effect can be ignored.

So, when someone talks about measuring “open circuit” voltage with a multimeter, what they really mean is shunting the circuit with 10Mohm and measuring the voltage across that resistor. The resistance can be equivalently expressed as 100nA/V. When you measure 10VDC, a 1uA current flows through the multimeter’s input impedance.

For the smallest of batteries, especially when discharged, you’d usually measure with voltmeter input impedance acting as a shunt, and then add an equal shunt across the input to halve the impedance and repeat the measurement. You can then plot this voltage against *shunt conductance* and extrapolate the open circuit voltage at shunt conductance=0S. Recall that shunt conductance is the reciprocal of shunt impedance.

There is a class of circuits called current sources, which have inherently high output impedances. Recall that an ideal current source has infinite output impedance. If current source loads are high impedances as well, the multimeter's impedance will skew the readings a lot, and may even prevent the circuit from working. The circuit nodes involved have to be buffered with a suitable voltage follower - a FET input op-amp, usually. The follower output can be measured with a multimeter. Decent current sources have impedances in 1-10Mohm range; precision ones go way past that.